# Why doesn't the shell require formal arguments in the function signature?

Tags: shell, unix

Why does a shell not need parameters for functions?
Example of addition function below that adds num1 and num2.
I mean that you don't write the parameters inside the () of the line function addition().

```
addition()
{
  echo $(($num1+$num2))
}
```

Comment: This function doesn't even use its parameters, so the question doesn't make sense. Did you mean `echo $(($1 + $2))` instead?

Comment: No, the user is asked for input, the variables num1 and num2 are used for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is *why does this function work, how does it get the num1 and num2 variables?"*, the answer is: it gets those variables from the *parent* context, for example this will echo `hello Jack`:

```
hello() {
    echo hello $name
}

name=Jack
hello
```

You can rewrite the function to use positional arguments like this:

```
hello() {
    echo hello $1
}

hello Jack
```

As per why not write variable names in the function declaration: that's just the way `bash` is made. From the man page:

```
Shell Function Definitions
   A shell function is an object that is called like a simple command  and
   executes  a  compound  command with a new set of positional parameters.
   Shell functions are declared as follows:

   name () compound-command [redirection]
   function name [()] compound-command [redirection]
          This defines a function named name.  The reserved word  function
          is  optional.   If  the  function reserved word is supplied, the
          parentheses are optional.  The body of the function is the  com‐
          pound  command  compound-command  (see Compound Commands above).
....
```

That is, the function declaration must be in one of the explained forms, with `()` (no variable names in between) mandatory when not using the `function` keyword, and optional otherwise.

Comment: It'd be more correct to say *it gets those variables from the parent context.*

Answer (score 1):

From the manpage:

> When a function is executed, the arguments to the function become the positional parameters during its execution.  The special parameter # is updated to reflect the change.  Special parameter 0 is unchanged.

In CS terms, bash functions don't use [formal parameters](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap34A/ch34A_3.html) because the positional parameters are always set when (and only when) you apply the function:

```
$ ##
$ # Show the function arguments
$ showParams() {
>    printf '%s\n' "$@"
$ }
$ showParams 1 2 3
1
2
3
$ set -- 1 2 3
$ printf '%s\n' "$@"
1
2
3
$ showParams # Here you can see the parameters in the shell are not set in the function application:
$
```

…but this also means bash does not support keyword arguments.

You may also wish to read the section under *Positional Parameters* in the manpage.

Answer (score 1):

Shell functions don't need prototypes because

- **All variables are string variables**. They get converted to numbers as needed e.g. when doing arithmetic. (BTW, declaring variables as integers is a shell extension not found in POSIX).
- The number of parameters passed is known when the function is called and available as `$#` so the function body can deal with variadic functions.

Comment: *All variables are string variables* What about shell support for arrays?

Comment: There are no arrays. Shells supporting arrays as an extension do so using a different syntax so they also need no prototypes.